# Seleccionar todos los elementos con un ID correlativo

Tags: jquery

Tengo 5 elementos que identifico con un id correlativo a los que le asigno una clase, y quiero cambiar esa clase cuando los selecciono o los deselecciono.

Los identifico del modo:

> #tab1 #tab2 #tab3 #tab4 #tab5

Probé a seleccionarlos del modo:

```
if($("div[id^='tab]".hasClass('sel')){
   $("div[id^='tab].removeClass('sel');
   $("div[id^='tab].addClass('nosel');
}
```

Pero el caso es que no hace nada. Pensé en ponerles a mayores una clase y a partir de esa nueva clase cambiar la clase **sel** ó **nosel** en función de si está activo o no. Pero prefiero hacerlo por id.

¿Cómo podría hacer esa selección por id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé que **HTML** tienes pero ibas bien encaminado con el **selector** que has usado. Te muestro un ejemplo funcional.

```js
$(function () {
  let seleccionados = $('div[id^="tab"]');
  
  seleccionados.css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tab1">1</div>
<div id="tab2">2</div>
<div id="tab3">3</div>
<div id="tab4">4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
```